# Ошибка при вводе

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, input, threading

Вылезает такая ошибка.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/cian_parser/v2/main.py", line 26, in main
    response = str(input(">>> ")).lower()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Скрипт исполняется на linux сервере. Ошибка вылезает не сразу, может сразу при запуске, может и через минут 10-20.

Comment: а Вы что-то вводите с клавиатуры? приложите часть кода, где возникает ошибка

Comment: Скрипт пишет в консоль status, я начинаю вводить один символ в консоль и сразу ошибка, до этого вводил команды - всё было отлично(в этой сессии). Иногда ошибка вылетает сразу при запуске.

Comment: Вы сначала считайте ввод, а потом уже вызывайте операции над ним.

Comment: @Boro8ey а что именно вводите? у меня на убунту сервере строка response = str(input(">>> ")).lower() отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: Команду status. Ввожу первый символ и ошибка выводится.
`while True:
        
        time.sleep(0.01)
        response = str(input(">>> ")).lower()`

Comment: @AnatolyKritskiy
`if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=main)
    my_thread.start()`

Comment: у меня не удалось повторить ошибку. Попробуйте отредактировать вопрос, добавив минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример Вашего кода, где будет появляться ошибка.

Comment: да скорее всего управляшка прилетела с сессии с недобитым mc.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно управляющая последовательность прилетела с терминала. Попробуйте ресетить терминал:

```
curses.reset_shell_mode()
```

или

```
curses.setupterm()
```

Или не использовать mc для навигации в папку со скриптом.

Comment: Я не использовал mc, максимум, что я использовал - это screen и подключался по ssh.